# Check inputs with trim function in php

Tags: php

When im validating a form with php, how can i check the text inputs with trim function?

```
    $error = array();
if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{
    if(empty($_POST['hir_cim'])) { $error[] = "A megnevezést kötelező kitölteni."; }
    if(empty($_POST['hir_rovid'])) { $error[] = "A rövid leírást kötelező kitölteni."; }
    if(empty($_POST['meta_cimsor'])) { $error[] = "A meta címsort kötelező kitölteni."; }
    if(empty($_POST['hir_seo'])) { $error[] = "A SEO url-t kötelező kitölteni."; }
}
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php

Comment: *"how can i check the text inputs with trim function?"* - Um... use it? `trim($var)`.

Comment: `trim()` does not check inputs. It just removes whitespace preceding or trailing your values (and other chars, too, if desired). Otherwise you just call it like you would any other function.

Comment: @John `does` probably ment to say `does not` Howdy by the way

Comment: @RiggsFolly Ahh, the power of a missing word. Good morning, Chris. :)

Comment: if(empty(trim($_POST['hir_cim']))) { $error[] = "A megnevezést kötelező kitölteni."; }


For that, i get this: Can't use function return value in write context in

Comment: [**RTM!**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

Answer (score 0):

trim() does not check inputs. It just removes whitespace preceding or trailing your values or other characters.